# mousewheel and mousemove conflicts in IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

i am binding both mousewheel and mousemove event to same element.

```
$(this.element).on("mousemove", this.ChartMouseMove);
var matched = jQuery.uaMatch(navigator.userAgent);
var eventName = matched.browser.toLowerCase() == "mozilla" ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";
$(this.element).on(eventName, this.chartMouseWheel);

ChartMouseMove: function () {},

chartMouseWheel: function () {},
```

when am mouse wheel the element in IE it triggers both the events "ChartMouseMove" as well as "chartMouseWheel"  but its working in other browsers like firefox and chrome.

i want to trigger only one event when am do "mousewheel" if am moving the element it will call  mousemove,it's fine. but in  IE when am start to mousewheel on the element it will call both the event function that raises the conflict problem.

i don't want to trigger both the events.  if am moving on the element need to call "mousemove"  and if am wheeling on the element need to call "mousewheel" only.

what's the problem in IE browser ? (IE10, IE9 )

jquery version -1.9

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: am not binding mousewheel inside mousemove handler.both will be binded seprately

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13900365/1414562  could help you