# How to use "input propertychange" events to capture just copy and paste by mouse

Tags: javascript, textarea, jquery

I want to capture change happened in textarea (keyup, and also copy&past), for keyup option i use :

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(){
   // ajax call here
});
```

i added this to capture pasting or cutting by mouse then trigger keyup event on the textarea:

```
$("textarea").on('input propertychange', function() {
    $(this).trigger(keyup);
});
```

the problem here is if i press a key in my keyboard , i get 2 ajax calls because the second function capture also keyup event.

Is there a way to prevent `$("textarea").on('input propertychange'...` from detecting a press key ?

Comment: Why not just use the second function?!

Comment: @TamerShlash because the second event doesn't work in all browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after doing some research i found a solution here :

[How to run a function once when binding to multiple events that all trigger in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900093/how-to-run-a-function-once-when-binding-to-multiple-events-that-all-trigger-in-j)

i think this is the best solution to prevent calling event twice in my situation

Answer (score 8):

Why not test this simplification? As I tested your code, without success on detecting keyup in 'input propertychange' event.

#### You ignore keyup event:

```
//$("textarea").keyup(function(){
//// ajax call here
//});
```

#### And capture only this (do ajax call with this):

```
$("textarea").on('input propertychange', function() {
  //$(this).trigger(keyup);
  // do ajax call here
});
```

the latter ignores only some control keys, ie, key without corresponding character input.

Comment: I found that use 'input propertychange' in iOS11 and when I delete up to 5 characters, it will show some space between cursor and the last letter.