# How to trigger callback on multiple events only once in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I need to do something only once when the user clicks on the page OR any key is pressed down. I would usually do this using the .one() function in jQuery, but the callback is called for both events once instead of only one time total:

```
$("html").one("click keydown", function() {
   alert("event");
});
```

I can't call `$(this).unbind("click keydown")` because I do not want to unbind the other events that might be bound to the element.

Edit:
I should had mentioned this before but the code that binds the event is called multiple times and I want the callback to run one time for each time it was binded. If the event was binded n times I want the callback to run n times.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63957634/9854149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your function outside event handler:

```
var onClickAndKeydown = function(){
    alert("event");
}
```

then add handler to events click and keydown to that function using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("html").on("click keydown", onClickAndKeydown);
```

and when you need, you can remove event handler for that function using [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$("html").off("click keydown", onClickAndKeydown);
```

The [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method removes event handlers that were attached with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). If you specify address to your function inside [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/), then will be removed handler only to that function, so handlers for other functions still will be handled.

Comment: calling $(this).off("click keydown", onClickAndKeydown); inside the callback is not unbinding the event for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was passing the parameters to the function in a wrong manner

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off) like,

```
$("html").on("click keydown", function(e) {
   alert(e.type);
   $(this).off("click keydown");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yqard/)

Answer (score 0):

Use namespaced event names

```
$("html").one("click.myonce keydown.myonce", function () {
    console.log("event");
    $(this).off('click.myonce keydown.myonce')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7tLkj/)

Comment: hm that wouldn't work on my case because the code that binds the event is called multiple times. I could append a unique number to the namespace for each event, but that is ugly.

Comment: Use a named function `function foo(){...}` and overwrite it with an empty body `window.foo = function() {};` after the first execution - It's the steamroller tactics but maybe its "smart" enough :)

Comment: @Hoffmann assuming the event is binded `n` times do you want the function to execute `n` times?

Comment: @Hoffmann Then I don't see any other solution than to use a unique namespace for each one... probably somebody will come up with a better solution

Comment: Epsil0neR answer should work since each time the code is invoked a new callback function is created, but for some reason it does not unbind the event.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write your own plugin for jQuery, which would handle this quite nicely;

```
jQuery.fn.onceFor = function (events, func) {
    var that = this;

    this.on(events, function () {
        that.off(events, func);

        return func.apply(this, arguments);
    });
};
```

... which you'd then call via;

```
$("html").onceFor("click keydown", function() {
   alert("event");
});
```